# Xbindkeys not working on Elementary OS Juno

Tags: release-juno, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been trying to create global hotkeys for Parlatype using `xbindkeys`, following instructions on Parlatype's [Github page](https://github.com/gkarsay/parlatype/issues/18).
So I added the following lines to `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
#Play/Pause
"qdbus com.github.gkarsay.parlatype /com/github/gkarsay/parlatype com.github.gkarsay.parlatype.PlayPause"
   Shift + space

#Jump back
"qdbus com.github.gkarsay.parlatype /com/github/gkarsay/parlatype com.github.gkarsay.parlatype.JumpBack"
   Shift+Alt + Left

#Jump forward
"qdbus com.github.gkarsay.parlatype /com/github/gkarsay/parlatype com.github.gkarsay.parlatype.JumpForward"
   Shift+Alt + Right
```

Unfortunately, as much as it had worked perfectly in past versions of Elementary OS, this time the process yields no results, Parlatype remained unresponsive both in the fore- and in the background.

Many thanks to everyone who will help me solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do column selection using Alt+Ctrl+"arrow up"/"Arrow down". Seems to be the keyboard selection in System Settings, Keyboard, "Switch Layout:". I am a European citizen, using "Euro on Five". Switching keyboard layouts is by default defined as Shift+Alt. In Geany this keyboard combination is defined as column selection. Using Shift+Alt changed the keyboard selection in stead of doing column selection.
I changed it into Left-Shift + Right-Shift. Now I can perform column selection in Geany. Maybe this helps you solve the issue.